# react-router-redux nested component not having params in ownProps

Tags: react-router-redux

I am using react-router-redux and I can't get the ownProps to have params in a deeply nested, connected component. Or is it only the component described in a  which get will the params?

So here is a little schema:

```
Route
 |___ LeveOne
         \__Some Dumb Component
                \___ Another dumb component
                       \__ A Connected Component
```

it's in the A Connected Component that I'm trying to get the ownProps.params, but can't.

The version of react-router-redux is 4.0.0

Thank you!